# No button to create a new script on my Pine Editor in TradingView

Tags: pine-script

When I open Pine Editor in my TradingView there is no button to create a new script.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom right corner you have `Open`, click it and you will have the menu from the bellow screenshot, then choose `New blank indicator`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "open". Further down you will find "New default build-in script...", "New blank indicator" and "New default strategy".
Choose one of them and the script name is changing to "unknown" so you can save it.

Answer (score 0):

At beginning I have the same issue. Basically if you started or opened a script, it's not created in some conditions. The solution for Mac is to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. In Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>